# Getting 502 Bad Getaway when doing Curl on facebook.com

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to make CURL requests with PHP and Guzzle. It works well on youtube.com, but the browser shows a 502 Bad Getaway error when trying to request facebook.com.

My code :

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'headers' => ['User-Agent' => null]
]);
$code = $res->getStatusCode();
```

The URLs I am testing :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skSPHfkIMow : OK returns 200
- https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=492187276105133&ref=sharing : Error, the browser shows a 502 Bad Getaway error.

Does Facebook block these kind of requests ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it does block those kinds of requests, i suggest you look into some web scraping if you got time, it's a cool topic, so, in short, you have to look like a browser, first just add browser headers to the request, and if that it does not work, sorry, you are going to have to consider headless chromium with selenium or something similar

Comment: OK, but it works when I am using a client like Paw or Postman. I tried setting a User-Agent header like 'Paw/3.4.0 (Macintosh; OS X/12.6.0) GCDHTTPRequest' but it does not work when running my PHP script in the browser. Also, I need to read OpenGraph metadata from a Facebook video page, so how can I achieve this ? thanks.